# NameError when using reload()

Tags: python

I've got file named `recommend.py`. It has a dict data named critics.

When I try to reload it in the interpreter it gives the following error:

```
>>> from recommend import critics
>>> reload(recommend.py)
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     NameError: name 'recommend' is not defined
>>>
```

I'm new to python. Please help me.

Comment: Depsite the obvious error - why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`recommend.py` is parsed as `recommend . py` which means that python looks for an object bound to the name `recommend` and then tries to get the `py` attribute from it.  That doesn't work because you don't have an object named `recommend` in the current namespace and because even if you did have an object bound to that name, it probably wouldn't have an attribute `py`.

Of course, you'll need to give `reload` an actual module object.  Something more like:

```
import recommend
reload(recommend)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) takes a module object, not a filename:

```
import recommend
reload(recommend)
```